# Criar e editar dados de uma tabela com relacionamento Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma tabela chamada `agenda`, dentre os campos desse agenda é possível adicionar vários responsáveis por ela, que são os usuários cadastrados no sistema, para isso existe um campo do tipo `multiple select`, que permite selecionar vários IDs de usuários, e para guardar esses vários "responsáveis", criei uma tabela chamada `agenda_responsaveis`, que salva o id da agenda (`agenda_id`) e o id de cada usuário (`user_id`).

Atualmente, ao criar a agenda, para salvar os responsaveis, eu percorre os dados do select com um foreach e insiro os dados na tabela `agenda_responsaveis`

Ex:

```
$create = Agenda::create($data);

        foreach ($request->responsavel_id as $key => $id) {

            AgendaResponsavel::create(array(
                'agenda_id' => $create->
                'user_id' => $id
            ));
        }
```

E na parte da edição da agenda, eu procuro todos os registros com o `agenda_id`, faço a exclusão dos dados antigos e insiro novamente os novos dados que vem do select. Faço dessa forma porque não possuo o id de cada registro da tabela `agenda_responsaveis`.

Ex:

```
AgendaResponsavel::where('agenda_id', $agenda_id)->delete();

foreach ($request->responsavel_id as $key => $id) {

            AgendaResponsavel::create(array(
                'agenda_id' => $agenda_id,
                'user_id' => $id
            ));
        }
```

gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais eficiente de se fazer isso? sem parecer uma "gambiarra"

Answer (score 1):

Como o amigo Jedson Melo disse você pode usar o `Eloquent` que auxilia no processo de criação dos relacionamentos nas bases de dados. 
Conforme a documentação os `models` podem se relacionar com outros abstraindo a relação de fato. 
Como identificado se trata de um relacionamento N*N, ou muitos para muitos, o que gera uma tabela pivô.
No laravel eu posso representar esse relacionamento de maneira mais simples. Dentro do seu model Agenda você deve criar uma função (geralmente nesse utiliza-se o nome do outro model do relacionamento no plural). Ficaria assim:

```
public function responsaveis(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'agenda_responsaveis', 'agenda_id', 'user_id');
}
```

O primeiro argumento é o caminho do outro model do relacionamento, o segundo(opcional) é o nome da tabela, ele é opcional pois caso você utilize o padrão laravel não é necessário passa-lo pois o laravel já identifica. Os dois outros também são opcionais e só remetem ao nome dos campos. Como seu caso os nomes se diferem um pouco do padrão, é bom passar.
Ai para inserir na tabela pivô há duas possibilidades:

- Usando o método `attach`
- Ou usando o método `sync`

O `attach` simplesmente associa na base. Que no caso é sua primeira necessidade.
Já o `sync` serve para o seu segundo problema. O que ele faz, toda vez que é chamado, é excluir os relacionamentos anteriores e mantém os mais atuais que você mandou. É algo como uma sincronização.
Então aproveitando o exemplo do amigo, você poderia utilizar o `attach` no momento de inserção:

```
//caso os ids estejam num array, você pode envia-los todos de uma vez
$agenda = Agenda::create($data);
$agenda->responsaveis()->attach($array_de_ids_responsaveis);
```

Ai para a edição você faria a busca e depois utilizaria o sync:

```
$agenda = Agenda::find($id_agenda);
$agenda->responsaveis()->sync($novos_ids);
```

Acho que é isso, qualquer dúvida consulte a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: Precisa ter o relacionamento na App\User também?

Comment: Não é necessário. Mas caso você queira  retornar as agendas ou inserir na tabela pivô a partir do model User ai você cria. Digamos que queira pegar as agendas de um responsável:
`$user = User:find($id);
$agendas = $user->agendas;
`. Enfim, caso não necessite para você manipular os dados através do outro model, você não precisa criar.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando os relacionamentos que o Eloquent ORM que o laravel proporciona. No seu caso você tem um relacionamento de Many to Many para entre agenda e responsável, então basta configurar as models seguindo a [Documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) e você poderá utilizar algo assim:

```
$agenda = Agenda::create($data);
$agenda->responsaveis()->attach($request->responsavel_id);
```